# How to open a window on a specific display in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, graphics

I've been tasked with modifying one of our c++ products to spawn a new window on a specific display in the Windows OS. This is for a client who needs to be able to configure a tiled multi-display visualization, where each display is driven by a separate graphics card on a single computer.

In linux, I can do this easily by starting an X server on each display, then starting multiple instances of the visualization software with the DISPLAY env var set appropriately. However, I'm lost when it comes to doing this in Windows. Any pointers/suggestions/examples?

Comment: don't know if there's a windows api for this, but I know that the AMD catalyst control panel, and certain utilities you can install, have the capability to target specific screens on a per-app basis. might want to dig into how those do their magic, if you don't get any help here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to enumerate all the monitors and check on their mappings on the [virtual screen (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145136.aspx).

Monitors are enumerated via a call to [EnumDisplayMonitors (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162610.aspx). This will enumerate a series of `HMONITOR` handles that you can pass to [GetMonitorInfo (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144901.aspx) to get the location of the monitor on the virtual screen.

There's also a whole guide to Multi-Monitor support that may also be worth reading.

[About Multiple Display Monitors (Windows) @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183314.aspx)

Some Caveats: Because the virtual screen is a user-controlled mapping, there's nothing preventing a user from setting up a monitor on the opposite physical side of where the monitor is placed in virtual coordinate space, and vice versa, as well as any number of other weird placement scenarios. Also, some display cards try to assume where the monitor is upon plug-in detection, which may be wrong from your software's point of view but could be caused by the user not paying attention to which display port maps to a left-hand side (if it is even labeled at all).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `EnumDisplayMonitors` function from the Win32 API to get info on each of your displays.

Once you have the rectangle for your required display, you know what to do =)

I'm pretty sure the displays are enumerated in order.  But if you are tiling, you could get a vector of all the display rectangles and then sort them.

I have a handy wrapper I wrote a while back to get all the monitor infos:

**Declaration**

```
class CMonitorInfoEx : public MONITORINFOEX
{
public:
    CMonitorInfoEx();

    LPCRECT GetRect() const { return &rcMonitor; }
    LPCRECT GetWorkRect() const { return &rcWork; }
    LPCTSTR DeviceName() const { return szDevice; }

    bool IsPrimary() const { return (dwFlags & MONITORINFOF_PRIMARY) ? true : false; }

    int Width() const { return rcMonitor.right - rcMonitor.left; }
    int Height() const { return rcMonitor.bottom - rcMonitor.top; }
    int WorkWidth() const { return rcWork.right - rcWork.left; }
    int WorkHeight() const { return rcWork.bottom - rcWork.top; }
};


class CSysDisplays
{
public:
    CSysDisplays();

    void Update();

    int Count() const;
    const CMonitorInfoEx& Get( int i ) const;

private:
    std::vector<CMonitorInfoEx> mInfo;
};
```

**Implementation**

```
BOOL CALLBACK MonitorEnumProc( __in  HMONITOR hMonitor, __in  HDC hdcMonitor, __in  LPRECT lprcMonitor, __in  LPARAM dwData )
{
    std::vector<CMonitorInfoEx>& infoArray = *reinterpret_cast< std::vector<CMonitorInfoEx>* >( dwData );
    CMonitorInfoEx info;
    GetMonitorInfo( hMonitor, &info );
    infoArray.push_back( info );
    return TRUE;
}

CMonitorInfoEx::CMonitorInfoEx()
{
    cbSize = sizeof(MONITORINFOEX);
}


CSysDisplays::CSysDisplays()
{
    Update();
}


void CSysDisplays::Update()
{
    mInfo.clear();
    mInfo.reserve( ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CMONITORS) );
    EnumDisplayMonitors( NULL, NULL, MonitorEnumProc, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&mInfo) );
}


int CSysDisplays::Count() const
{
    return (int)mInfo.size();
}


const CMonitorInfoEx& CSysDisplays::Get( int i ) const
{
    return mInfo[i];
}
```