# I am trying to send a window (application) from the main monitor (touch screen) to a secondary monitor using the same graphics card on the same host

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-c++-6

**I am trying to send a window (application) from the main monitor (touch screen) to a secondary monitor using the same graphics card on the same host**

I spent a long time gathering data, trying to get a clear idea:

```
The MoveDown MOVEDEV_PARAMS

BOOL GetWindowRect(
    HWND hWnd,      // handle to window
    LPRECT lpRect   // window coordinates
);
```

AND...
And the following, but my brain can't put them together into something useful for me

```
BOOL EnumDisplayDevices(  
    LPCTSTR lpDevice,                // device name
    DWORD iDevNum,                   // display device
    PDISPLAY_DEVICE lpDisplayDevice, // device information
    DWORD dwFlags                    // reserved);
```

```
BOOL EnumDisplayMonitors(
    HDC hdc,                   // handle to display DC 
    LPCRECT lprcClip,          // clipping rectangle 
    MONITORENUMPROC lpfnEnum,  // callback function
    LPARAM dwData              // data for callback function 
);
```

```
BOOL EnumDisplaySettings(  
    LPCTSTR lpszDeviceName,  // display device
    DWORD iModeNum,          // graphics mode
    LPDEVMODE lpDevMode      // graphics mode settings);
```

[How to open a window on a specific display in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466735/how-to-open-a-window-on-a-specific-display-in-windows/14466919#14466919)

```
    //VisualAPP Open
    SHELLEXECUTEINFO sei;
    ZeroMemory(&sei, sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO));
    
    sei.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
    sei.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
    sei.lpVerb = _T("open");
    sei.lpFile = _T("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\xxx.lnk");
    sei.nShow = SW_SHOW;
    
    if(ShellExecuteEx(&sei))    // Execute successfully
    {
        MoveApp();          // Moving program window

        if (sei.hProcess)
            WaitForSingleObject(sei.hProcess, INFINITE);
    }
    else
    {
        CString s;
        s.Format(_T("ShellExecuteEx error,errer code:%d"), GetLastError());
        // s = GetLastError();
        MessageBox(s);
    }

and the like...
```

There was a lot of enthusiastic user data that was very helpful to me, now how do I do development in VC6 is also important.

There is no problem in Visual stubio 2019, but not in Visual c++ 6.0 (maybe different support standards).

It made my feature development very difficult, and we were using VC6.

**We cannot upgrade vc6 to vs19(VSCode) in a short time.  Do you have a better way to solve the imminent problem.**

This is probably the most important thing for ‘me to achieve immortality ’

Comment: You cannot launch a program on a specific display using `ShellExecute`. You would need to use `ShellExecuteEx` instead (which you should anyway, if error handling is something you care about).

Comment: Thanks for your reminding. I have finished the update.  @IInspectable

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is here. If you wish that the system positions a window on a particular monitor, you're going to have to populate the `hMonitor` member of the [`SHELLEXECUTEINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-shellexecuteinfow) structure and set the `SEE_MASK_HMONITOR` flag.